# What is the fastest way to calculate fog of war?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization

I have the following function in my FogOfWar class, it calculates if its team can see the position that is passed on the arguments:

```
package mwoke {
    public class FogOfWar {
        public var game:Game;
        public var team:int;
        private var cache:Vector.<CachePos> = new Vector.<CachePos>();
        private var chars:Vector.<Character> = new Vector.<Character>();

        public function FogOfWar($game:Game, $team:int) {
            game = $game;
            team = $team;
        }

        public function think():void {
            cache.length = 0;
            chars.length = 0;

            var ent:Character;
            for(var i:int = 0; i < game.entities.length;++i) {
                if(game.entities[i] == null) continue;
                if(!(game.entities[i] is Character)) continue;
                ent = Character(game.entities[i]);
                if(ent.team != team) continue;
                if(ent.vision <= 0.0) continue;
                chars.push(ent);
            }
        }

        public function canSee(x:Number, y:Number):Boolean {
            if(x < game.minX) return false;
            if(y < game.minY) return false;
            if(x >= game.maxX) return false;
            if(y >= game.maxY) return false;

            for each(var v:CachePos in cache) {
                if(v.x == x && v.y == y) {
                    return v.result;
                }
            }
            var res:Boolean = false;

            for each(var ent:Character in chars) {
                if(Game.distance(x, y, ent.x, ent.y) < ent.vision) {
                    res = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            var tmp:CachePos = new CachePos();
            tmp.x = x;
            tmp.y = y;
            tmp.result = res;
            cache.push(tmp);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
internal class CachePos {
    public var x:Number;
    public var y:Number;
    public var result:Boolean;
}
```

My problem is that, with only 3 characters in the game, it can only run 4000 times per second, which is not too much.

I can implement a cache, so it caches the most commons positions, but, what else can I do to optimize it?

Comment: what about the Game.distance method, is it fast enough?

Comment: It's `Math.sqrt((x1 - x2)*(x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2)*(y1 - y2))`, and it's inlined using an optimizer

Comment: I was thinking about storing all the characters in an vector, so it doesn't need to loop through all the entities

Comment: Updated the code, also, instead of a 2d cache array, I preferred a 1d one, because it saves much more memory. The think function is called every frame from the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your characters have a viewing radius, you could maintain a data structure that is updated as friendly characters move around, something that indicates which parts of the map are visible.

Then checking to see if something is visible is as quick as checking the data structure value for that location on the map.

EDIT:

You could also used squared distance instead of absolute distance, which avoids a call to the (somewhat expensive) `Math.sqrt` function.  Basically, make a `Game.DistanceSquared < entity.VisionDistanceSquared` check.

Comment: Well, then it would need to generate the whole world every frame

Answer (score 0):

how about maintaining a list of objects that represent the character position and viewing radius as circles on a sprite (that's not part of the display list), every time someone moves, their circle is updated by the character or an intermediary class. That way you don't have to keep going through a loop every time.

when you want to see if a point is within the FOW, you can do a hit test on the sprite with all the circles. The added advantage is that you could even use the data to draw the FOW.

The caveat; while I think using internal functions should be faster (like hit test) I haven't tested it so it might not work better. The trick with using this is to not include it in the display list, once you add the fow sprite to the display list, you will see a performance decrease.